# Magento 1.6.2.0 — en_GB translate.csv isn't translating

Tags: magento

I'm trying to alter all occurrences of Shipping & Handling in my Magento site with Shipping & Handling (Incl.Tax).

I had a good search around and found that I needed to create a new translate.csv file and put it in the folder:

/app/design/frontend/package/theme/locale/en_GB/

So, I created a translate.csv file with the following inside:

```
"Shipping & Handling";"Shipping & Handling (Incl.Tax)"
"Shipping &amp; Handling";"Shipping &amp; Handling (Incl.Tax)"
```

and uploaded it to /app/design/frontend/package/theme/locale/en_GB/

I then cleared the magento cache and refreshed everything but the translation doesn't work, does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified English (Great Britain) in Locale Options setting in admin area?

If no, you need to go to System -> Configuration, choose the needed store view and find Locale options section under General tab. Next, from Locale drop-down, select the right one (the first comes language, the second – country, for example, for Canadian English it would be English (Canada)).

Also you need to use comma (,) as separator not ;

```
"Shipping & Handling","Your text goes here"
```

Comment: try to empty var/cache folder

Comment: I've edited my answer, but you need to use comma as separator

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem on magento 1.7; there seems to be a bug in magento core, so that magento prefers the translations in /app/locale over those in local theme folders. i found this solution in another thread (don't remember where):

fix or override `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php`, method `_getTranslatedString` :

change from:

```
if (array_key_exists($code, $this->getData())) {
    $translated = $this->_data[$code];
}
elseif (array_key_exists($text, $this->getData())) {
    $translated = $this->_data[$text];
}
else {
    $translated = $text;
}
```

to:

```
if (array_key_exists($text, $this->getData())) {
   $translated = $this->_data[$text];
}
elseif (array_key_exists($code, $this->getData())) {
    $translated = $this->_data[$code];
}
else {
    $translated = $text;
}
```

that fixed it for me.